# How to get a specific value from a text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline, readfile, filereader

I have a .txt file:

```
80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160   
100,20,22,24,26,28,26,28,29,27   
110,30,32,34,36,37,39,37,39,40  
120,40,41,42,44,45,46,48,47,49
```

which represents a table with prices for blinds, the first row is the width of the blind and the first column without 80 is the height. The rest of the numbers are the prices.

I already did this using c# but in java I have no idea what to do, in c# my code looks like this and everything is fine. Can somebody show me the same thing in java?
theWidth and theHeight are text fields where I have to type the dimensions.

```
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"tabel.txt");
                string[] aux = lines[0].Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < aux.Length-1; i++)
                {
                    if (aux[i] == theWidth.ToString())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(aux[i]);
                        indiceLatime = i;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    aux = lines[i].Split(',');
                    if (aux[0] == theHeight.ToString())
                    {
                        showPrice.Text = aux[indiceLatime + 1];
                    }
                }
```

In java I tried something like this:

```
try {
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tabel.txt"));
        int theWidth = 90;
        int theHeight = 100;
        int indiceLatime = 0;
        String line;

        try {
            while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] aux = line.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
                    if (aux[i].equals(Integer.toString(theWidth))) {

                        indiceLatime = i;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < aux.length; i++) {
                    if (aux[0].equals(Integer.toString(theHeight))) {
                        System.out.println("price: " + aux[indiceLatime]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So the price is in theHeight's row of theWidth's index which I am trying to get somehow. Is there somebody who can show me how can I get the correct number(price) out from the row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use FileReader like this:

```
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // code here to handle the current readed line

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**[Edit]**

Regarding to your updates, i have edit you code, please check it.

```
int widthIndex = 90;
    int hightIndex = 100;
    int indiceLatime = 0;
    boolean lookForWidth = true;

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("table.txt"));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] aux = line.split(",");

            if(lookForWidth) {// this flag to look for width only at the first time.
                for (int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
                    if(widthIndex == Integer.parseInt(aux[i].trim())) {
                        indiceLatime = i;
                        lookForWidth = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
                if(hightIndex == Integer.parseInt(aux[0])) {
                    System.out.println(aux[indiceLatime]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but this looks like c#.  The OP is asking how to do it in Java.

Comment: It may look like C#, but it's not. Java.

Comment: Java does not look like C#, but C# look like Java. :D

Comment: C# looks a lot like Java, but just different enough for Microsoft to avoid getting sued again.  :) :) [It's a good language, though.]

Comment: Ok but let's say I want to find out a rollershutters price for which the width is 90 and it's height is 100, the program should take out it's price from the text file and I showed you how the text file looks like. the price is 22 if you take a look at the sample I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
String filePath = <Your file Path>;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath ));
        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        while (line != null || !line.equals(null)) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line=br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```